# How to print something to the console from OpenMP source Code?

Tags: clang, openmp, llvm, llvm-clang

I am modifying OpenMP source Code, and I want to make sure that it is indeed working.
For example the following code:

```
#include "omp.h"

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,4)
    for(i=0;i<1000;++i)
    {
        int x = 4+i;
    }
}
```

Should call __kmpc_dispatch_init_4()
And I have verified this by using emit-llvm option in clang.

To double check I added the following print statement:

```
void __kmpc_dispatch_init_4(ident_t *loc, kmp_int32 gtid,
                            enum sched_type schedule, kmp_int32 lb,
                            kmp_int32 ub, kmp_int32 st, kmp_int32 chunk) {
  KMP_DEBUG_ASSERT(__kmp_init_serial);
  printf("%s\n", "Hello OpenMP");

#if OMPT_SUPPORT && OMPT_OPTIONAL
  OMPT_STORE_RETURN_ADDRESS(gtid);
#endif
  __kmp_dispatch_init<kmp_int32>(loc, gtid, schedule, lb, ub, st, chunk, true);
}
```

But when I am compiling the code, I am not getting this output on terminal.

I am compiling the code like this:

```
llvm_build/bin/clang sc.c  -L/usr/local/lib -fopenmp
```

And after building the openmp source code the output of `sudo make install` is this:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libomp.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/omp.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/omp-tools.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/ompt.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libomptarget.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libomptarget.rtl.x86_64.so
```

To cross check if this is used I used:

```
ldd a.out
```

And the output is:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff25bb6000)
    libomp.so => /usr/local/lib/libomp.so (0x00007f75a52c6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f75a50a7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f75a4cb6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f75a4ab2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f75a558a000)
```

So I am assuming it should be using the code that I have modified.
But not able to see the output of the print statement.
I have also tried using fprintf(stderr, ....)
But doesn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should flush the output using `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` to enforce the line to be printed in the console.
Moreover, you should also ensure that `/usr/local/lib/libomp.so` is the good one by just checking the modification date of the file (with the `stat` command).
If the loaded file is not the good one you can force it with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_PRELOAD` environment variables.
If this is not sufficient, you can use the `nm` or `objdump` tools to check the *dynamic* symbols: the function should be undefined in your program and provided by the modified LLVM OpenMP runtime.

PS: If none of this works, I strongly advise you to build your program and the OpenMP runtime library with debugging (and tracing) information so you can use debuggers like `gdb` in order to track function calls.